# Create a dynamic grid like view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

For creating a structure like the image in android, I tried the following code.

But showing this error. Please help

My code looks like

```
public void setValues(){

    LinearLayout table=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainWrap);

    LinearLayout row=new LinearLayout(this);;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        if(i%2==0){

        row= new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }


        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/2)-10,(height/2)-10);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        if(i%2==0){
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CACACA"));
        }
        else {
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
        }

        ProgressBar pr=new ProgressBar(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params_p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((width/6),(width/6));
        params_p.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
        pr.setLayoutParams(params_p);
        layout.addView(pr);



        ImageView im=new ImageView(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params_im = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((width/2),(width/2));
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.man);

        im.setLayoutParams(params_im);
        layout.addView(im);

        row.addView(layout);
        table.addView(row);
    }
```

Error is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What line give you the error?

Comment: while running this code, fatal error happening and crash the application

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but what line give you this error? Look at your error log

Comment: Well thats obvious. Now go and look at the stack trace and see which line in your app that crash corresponds to

Comment: I am new to android, how to find out in which line making error ?

Comment: log cat tab in your ide

Comment: Unrelated error: you're doing row= new LinearLayout(this); twice

Comment: @NickCardoso can you show a sample code plz ?

Comment: How can you possibly need that explaining as well? just search your code for row=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling the problem is here:

```
  LinearLayout row=new LinearLayout(this);;
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
```

The first time it loops `row` will be replaced by your second assignment of it and held in the variable OUTSIDE of the loop, the second time it is not replaced and because it is outside of the loop, it is the same `row` you're trying to add to the `table` again. Just swap the order of the lines above.